# How to pass HTML Body as Paramaeter for DisplayNewAppointmentForm

Tags: office-js, outlook-web-addins

How to pass HTML body as parameters for displayNewAppointmentForm in Office JS.

When I tried the below, the HTML tags are also displayed in the body of meeting

[image]

If I try to set only start and end times using displayNewAppointmentForm and then try to set the body using setAsync, I am getting the error that the property or method is not supported.

How can we pass the CoercionType:HTML also in displayNewAppointmentForm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently the feature:Adding HTML body using displayNewAppointmentForm, as you requested, is not a part of the product. We track Outlook add-in feature requests on our [user-voice](https://officespdev.uservoice.com/forums/224641-general/category/131778-outlook-add-ins) page. Please add your request there. Feature requests on user-voice are considered when we go through our planning process.

You may be trying to call body.setAsync from the same window where you called displayNewAponitmentForm from. The context of item there is the item your main window is pointing to, not the new appointment form. The reason you see the error with setAsync is because I assume you have a read mode item open in the main window. If you want to set the body on the new appointment form that opened, you will have to re-open the add-in on the new appointment form that just opened and then call item.body.setAsync so that the item's context is now the appointment.

Comment: Thanks Team. Posted the idea in user-voice.